# Is OS X still using Mach as kernel and why did they move it?

Tags: mac, kernel, osx-yosemite

When I updated to Yosemite I found out that Mach_kernel was no longer present in root (I develop a lot so I have show all hidden files set to YES). After a bit of searching I found the new location of it.`/System/Libary/Kernels/kernel` It was also renamed to kernel.

## My Question

Do they still use Mach as their *'base kernel'* and also **why did they move it** there in the first place?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `/System/Library/Kernels/kernel` ?

Comment: @user1155120 I thought it was. My mistake

Comment: That's still 'Library' not 'Libary'.  If you go to [Kernel and Device Drivers Layer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemTechnology/SystemTechnology.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH207-BCICAIFJ) and scroll down to The Kernel, you'll find a description of what part Mach plays in the OS X kernel. The revision history for this document shows it was updated for 10.11.

Comment: If you were to look in the [System Integrity Protection Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide.pdf) for OS X you'd find that /System is a protected location while / isn't included as a System Only Location (Page 5).  You could wonder if Yosemite was originally supposed to have SIP, and the location of the kernel is preparatory for SIP, now in El Capitan.